# Link between A-B deleted when C is deleted

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my datamodel:

Exam:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int TimeLimit { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public QuestionSuite Suite { get; set; }
}
```

QuestionSuite

```
public class QuestionSuite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TimeLimit { get; set; }
}
```

Question

```
/* Some data*/
public virtual List<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
public virtual List<Result> Results { get; set; }
public virtual List<QuestionSuite> QuestionSuites { get; set; }
```

`Question` represent a simple question, with it's answers and stuff. `Exam` represent a current ongoing examination, that has a user doing it, some questions, and might be created from a `QuestionSuite`. Finally, `QuestionSuite` is a custom suite of question that any user can create and share.

The reason there is so much reference is that I need `Exam` to remember the suite to notify the creator at the end of the exam, but it still needs to remember the question because not all exams are created from suites.

Now for the problem: After an exam is finished, I create a Result, notify the suite creator if exam had one, then delete the `Exam` object with the following code:

```
public void DeleteExamByUserId(int userId)
{
    //Context.Exams.RemoveRange(Context.Exams.Where<Exam>(exam => exam.User.Id == userId));
    foreach(Exam e in Context.Exams)
    {
        if (e.User.Id == userId)
            Context.Exams.Remove(e);
    }
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`EntityFramework` creates a `QuestionSuiteQuestions` table to link questions and suites. When an exam is deleted, `QuestionSuiteQuestions` are also deleted for no reason.

Do you know why this would happen? Is there a way to see the logic behind relations and deletions somewhere?

Comment: Could be a cascading delete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Comment: That is what I though too, but Exams do not use QuestionSuiteQuestions at all, and neither questions suites nor questions are affected by the deletion :/

Comment: Try to work up a self-contained repro, and use EF logging to examine the database traffic.

Comment: I added the following code:

        `var entries = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged);
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity Name: {0}", entry.Entity.GetType().FullName);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", entry.State);
            }
            Context.SaveChanges();`

After the remove part. It only shows one entry, the Exam. Yet the questionsuiteQuestion relations are deleted. It makes 0 sense.

Comment: Ok I tried removing the relation from exam to QuestionSuite completely and QuestionSuiteQuestions data are still removed, so I will close this and open another ticket with my findings.